# Firefox 33.0 won't open a specific local application: Error code: sec_error_invalid_key

Tags: firefox

Firefox upgraded to version 33.0 this morning. Since then, I cannot load a specific local application over HTTPS -- note that it uses a self-signed certificate. It displays the following error message:

`The key does not support the requested operation. (Error code: sec_error_invalid_key)`

I cannot see anything in Firebug. I restarted Firefox in safe mode, to make sure no add-on was the problem. I also cleaned my cache and cookies. The same application opens fine with Chrome, and Firefox can open other applications that use HTTPS with a self-signed certificate.

Any idea how I could troubleshoot this issue?

**Edit:** Mozilla has made several important changes to security in Firefox 33.0. Details can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/33/Site_Compatibility#Security).

In my particular situation, the self-signed certificate was blocked because it was deemed too weak:

> RSA 512, 1000 and 1023-bit certificates are now blocked by Firefox since they are not sufficient for security. Most certificates currently being issued should have a 2048-bit key length.

Comment: Encounter the same issue.
Another thread, https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1018618, mentioned that it happens during beta and no action taken since by FF.

Comment: I am getting the same thing. I'm not sure there is anything you can do in FF 33 right now. Even if you tried to remove the cert and installing it again, it doesn't clear up.

Comment: I had uninstall 33.0, install 32.0, remove the profile, create a new one, and finally replace the profile with the old one. Everything was working fine. Then I installed 33.0 again, and the issue was back.

Comment: Firefox 33 doesn't support self signed certificates. I had to go back to 32 because I maintain several routers and severs where I'm the only one there and just used self signed certs.
No word from them how this will turn out. Report it to them. There should always be an advanced "hidden" option to turn off or on anything. I hope they change their mind, or I guess I stay on version 32 for a long long time.

Comment: You are wrong. Firefox 33 supports self-signed certificates. I suspect that a key length is a problem here.

Comment: Yes Webmin seems to be one of the main culprits here with 512 bit keys which are too short for Firefox 33 http://superuser.com/a/829979/7018

Comment: Just a note that the suitability of this question for Stack Overflow is being discussed on meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276671/scope-of-software-tools-commonly-used-by-programmers-in-stack-overflow?cb=1

Answer (score 14):

I have encountered the same problem after upgrading to Firefox 33 with Tomato router. The key length is a problem here.

Tomato generates 512 bit long RSA key by default. However, Firefox 33 requires minimum 1024 bit key.

I had to manually generate a longer key in Tomato.

I did that following way:

1. Log in using ssh to the router.
2. `cd /tmp`
3. `cp /usr/sbin/gencert.sh .`
4. `chmod +w gencert.sh`
5. Edit the `gencert.sh` file you copied and change the following line:

   `openssl req -new -out /tmp/cert.csr -config openssl.config -keyout /tmp/privkey.pem -newkey rsa:512 -passout pass:password`

   into:

   `openssl req -new -out /tmp/cert.csr -config openssl.config -keyout /tmp/privkey.pem -newkey rsa:1024 -passout pass:password`
6. `./gencert.sh $(date +%s)`
7. `nvram unset https_crt_file`
8. `nvram commit`
9. `service httpd restart`

Now httpd will use the new certificate. If you have "Save in NVRAM" checkbox enabled it will be saved in NVRAM and survive router reboot.

Do not check "Regenerate" checkbox, because automatically regenerated certificates are still 512 bit long.

If you remove your certificate from NVRAM, you must repeat procedure described above.

### Firefox 34 and newer:

Starting from Firefox 34 you need to additionally enable SSL 3.0 support in Firefox configuration:

1. Enter `about:config` address in the URL bar.
2. Set the following options to **0**:

   ```
   security.tls.version.fallback-limit
   security.tls.version.min
   ```

Comment: Is there any reason why you didnt edit the gencert.sh file in place ie make the changes permanent?

Comment: Router's file system is read-only. You can write to it only by uploading firmware blobs.

Comment: Is there any way to enable other ciphers other than SSLv3.0 for httpd on tomato router? This is with regards to Firefox 34 dropping support for SSLv3.0. I would like to avoid having to use SSLv3.0 altogether rather then using the `about:config` settings.

Answer (score 3):

For Webmin:
I created a new ssl certificate and now it is working with FF 33.

Webmin -> Webmin Configuration -> SSL Encryption -> Self-Signed Certificate

Comment: For Webmin see also here http://superuser.com/questions/826232/how-to-bypass-the-secure-connection-failed-warning-in-firefox-33

Answer (score -6):

turned off Hardware acceleration in the Options> Advanced > General Tab
Problem cleared up